# How do I take user inputs and store them to search an website later in swift Xcode

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I am trying to make an iOS app that takes a users inputs and searches yelp for recommendations. I have all the inputs set up. (Number of people, preferences...etc) I am trying to figure out how to store this data briefly and then use all the responses later to search yelp to retrieve data back from yelp. Any ideas?

Comment: Store them in `struct` or `class`.  Put them in Realm database or store them CoreData (although, that might be a little heavy-handed ).  Put them in `UserDefaults`.  The context of your question is to broad.  How long is `later`?  Same session? Different sessions?

Comment: it would be the same session @MadProgrammer

Comment: I'd consider simply keeping them in some kind of cache or passing them to the next view controller if the work flow allows

Answer (score 0):

Its simple.
On your searchViewController (or any class), simply make a struct.
Like this ;

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController{

struct userInputs {

 static var searches = [String]() // creates string array
 static var userInputs = [String]() 
 static var lastSearchedValue = " " 

 }


}
```

Now you can call these values anywhere in the app like this

```
HomeViewController.userInputs.searches[index] //if its tableview then [indexPath.row]
```

or you can simply define this struct OUTSIDE of all classes and then you would be able to call them with

```
userInputs.searches[index]
```

Use whichever feels better for you. You can use the values wherever you want , in any class or view :)

If you want these values to be used in the next session ,it would be better to store them in userdefaults like this

```
//Set Value
UserDefaults.standard.set("value", forKey: "Key")

//Get
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Key")

//Remove
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "Key")
```